# uCLinux Maxim14830 Driver Not Probing

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, stm32, uclinux

I am trying to get a Maxim14830 evaluation board to work with my Emcraft STM32F4 SOM. My SOM is running the Emcraft uClinux kernel 2.0.0 (Forked from Kernel 4.4) [on github here](https://github.com/EmcraftSystems/linux-upstream/tree/linux-cortexm-2.0.0) (I have plans to attempt this with Kernel version 4.5 as well).

The driver is not registering the 4 ttyMAX[n] devices. Upon further inspection, none of the max310x.c driver code is actually being executed based on the printk's I've added. I would at least expect the probe function to run during boot.

The source code on github for the maxim14830 (protocol?) driver is here [max310x.c](https://github.com/EmcraftSystems/linux-upstream/blob/linux-cortexm-2.0.0/drivers/tty/serial/max310x.c)

The source code on github for the spi (controller?) driver is here [spi-stm32.c](https://github.com/EmcraftSystems/linux-upstream/blob/linux-cortexm-2.0.0/drivers/spi/spi-stm32.c)

I have been able to add an spidev device fine, so my belief is that this is a problem unique to the maxim14830.

I see a spi device here:

```
/sys/devices/platform/soc/40003800.spi/spi_master/spi1/spi1.0 # cat modalias 
spi:maxim14830
```

I see the max310x driver here:

```
/sys/bus/spi/drivers/max310x
```

I see the following devicetree entries:

```
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/soc/spi@40003800/max14830@0 # cat compatible 
maxim,maxim14830
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/clocks/osc_max14830
```

My devicetree looks like so:

```
&spi_2 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_spi_2>;
    cs-gpios = <&gpiob 9 OUT>;
    timeouts = <3>;

    max14830: max14830@0 {
        status = "okay";
        compatible="maxim,maxim14830";
        reg = <0>;
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
        interrupt-parent = <&exti>;
        interrupts = <10>;
        clocks = <&spi_uart_clk>;
        clock-names = "xtal";
    };

    spidev: spidev@2 {
            status = "disabled";
            compatible = "linux,spidev";
            spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
            reg = <0>;
    };
};
```

I'm able to compile my device tree blob, and uboot the corresponding linux image fine. From my printk's, stm32_spi_probe is being called from the "Controller Driver," but to my knowledge no max310x.c driver code is being called after..

Where should I go to debug this further? This is my first embedded linux project and I could use some pointers..

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in device tree compatible entry. From the driver code here https://github.com/EmcraftSystems/linux-upstream/blob/linux-cortexm-2.0.0/drivers/tty/serial/max310x.c#L1275 the compatible property is `maxim,max14830`. But you have used `maxim,maxim14830`, check with proper compatiable property name.

Comment: Ah darn that was stupid. Thanks. Now I see the driver getting probed but still no tty devices. This is much more possible to debug however. Thanks

Comment: If anyone else is using this same setup you may need to update the revision mask and ID in the max310x.c driver code. See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/11652fc7b7e381a8d886ae1393e00512b71fe17d#diff-901fc56f0e40687499e3c2eba95f2767